# fs.WriteFile launches callback before actually writing the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following express request callback

```
zip.addLocalFolder(`/path/to/folder`, `./`);
var data = zip.toBuffer();
fs.writeFile(`path/to/download.zip`,data,function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.download(`path/to/download.zip`)
});
```

The fs.writeFile seems to be writing the file after calling the callback function.

**Edit**: the file is being written successfully. It is the fact that it is being written after I do `res.download()` that causes the error

If I call `res.download()` in a setTimeout, of 1 second, the execution ends successfully.

I get this error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'path/to/download.zip`

Changing the code to

```
zip.addLocalFolder(`/path/to/folder`, `./`);
var data = zip.toBuffer();
fs.writeFileSync(`path/to/download.zip`,data);
res.download(`path/to/download.zip`);
```

has the same effect.

The library I use, `adm-zip`, has a method for writing the zip file, and working with that has the very same effect.

Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Replace `fs.writeFileAsync(`path/to/download.zip`,data);` with `fs.writeFileSync(`path/to/download.zip`,data);` Check this [link](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) for Synchronous file write in nodejs.

Comment: @LilFlower , that is not the case. It will still fail because issue comed from the incorrect/not existing path to the file.

Comment: @LilFlower you are right, my bad, alltough it still fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that native file writing methods in nodejs will fail if the selected folder does not exist.
So before writing to `path/to/folder/download.zip` you need to make sure that all these folders `path/to/folder` already exist.

There are few methods of how achieve that. For example the `fs.mkdir` method available from Node v10.12

```
fs.mkdir('/path/to/folder', { recursive: true }, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  ... your write file code here
});
```

In the example above, node will firstly create all the folders in the path (see the `recursive:true` option) and then you can write file there.

**Important note**:

If you are sure, that all directories exist, then the issue is the wrong path passed to the method. Consider using the global `__dirname` [variable](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) in order to resolve correct path to the directory of your script file. Also you may use `./` prefix in path if the path should be relative to the place where app was executed.

Comment: The thing is that they exist.
The thing that is returning the error is res.download() as it does not find the file.
fs.writeFile, actually writes the file succesfully.
The thing is that the writing finishes, after the callback is called.

Comment: If I call res.download() in a setTimeout, of 1 seccond, the execution ends sucesfully

Comment: Update - You were verry right, and I was verry wrong.
The name of the file in my code contined a Date.now() to keep as a timestamp.
Turns out the Date.now() inside the file writer, is diferent from the other one
My bad :D

Comment: @IonutEugen , happy that you found that :)
P.S. If you like to use a timestamp as a kind of id (what is quite bad idea), then firstly assign Date.now() result into a variable and then use that variable wherever you need, do not call Date.now() again as it will not be the same, even in synchronous code.